# Django per-view caching: set expiry time rather than cache timeout?

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I'm using Django caching with memcached and I want to use [per-view caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

However I'd like to know if I can set an expiry time for the page (e.g. 4am today EST) rather than the cache timeout in seconds.

If I want the page to stay cached for 15 minutes, then I just do this:

```
@cache_page(60 * 15)
```

But how do I say "cache this page until tomorrow at 4am EST"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a nice built in way to do it, but if not you could create your own decorator that would essential do the same thing as [`cache_page`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/cache.py#L7)

But you could give your decorator a time string and inside of it, you could calculate the number of seconds until that time, then just call the original [cache function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/cache.py#L31), with the seconds until the time you specified